# Can i still store value in session if in browser cookie is disabled?

Tags: asp.net, session

Can i still store value in session if in browser cookie is disabled?

Comment: There are "degrees" of cookies - by default browser will block third party or "permanent" cookies, which won't affect Session values. Only if user disable all cookies including "memory only" cookies the Session will stop working, and you'll have to use cookieless state like CD showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cookieless Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).

In ASP.NET, the necessary session-to-user link may optionally be established without using cookies. Interestingly enough, you don't have to change anything in your ASP.NET application to enable cookieless sessions, except the following configuration setting.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

Comment: Please note that cookieless sessions are *EXTREMELY INSECURE* and will make your application extremely vulnerable to session hijacking attacks. See http://www.developerfusion.com/article/6678/top-10-application-security-vulnerabilities-in-webconfig-files-part-one/6/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what language you're working in, though the previous answer seems to assume you're working in ASP.NET. If you're working in Java, the HttpSession (server-side construct) holds values which are independent of cookies. In oher words, you can store sesson vaues on the server regardless of whether the client side browser has enabled cookies.

Comment: please see the tag before making such kind of comment. It has been tagged with ASP.Net.